# Is there any way to assign a string to a character array separate from its declaration?

Tags: c

I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
char s[10][10];
s[10] = "Hi!";
printf("%s",s[1]);
return 0;
}
```

In which the compiler gave me this error:

```
".......lvalue expected"
```

I just began studying C, so I don't have the idea on how to do this.

Comment: You might note that `s[10]` is out of bounds, so if the assignment worked, you'd be creating a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).  Also, you should declare the return type of `main()` explicitly — it is `int`; you should do the same for every other function you write.  C99 requires it; if you're using an older compiler, find out whether there are warning options to help.  For GCC, using `-std=c99 -Wall` is a good start (or `-std=gnu99`); using `-Wextra` too can avoid some other errors.  Do pay attention to compiler warnings (as well as errors).  GCC's `-Werror` can be useful for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can either initialise at definition time, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10][10] = { "Hello", "Hi!", "Bonjour", "Hola", "", "", "", "", "", "" }; 

    printf("%s\n", s[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

or use `strcpy()` to assign a string later, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10][10];

    strcpy(s[1], "Hi!");   // s[1] = "Hi!"
    printf("%s\n", s[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `"Hi!"` in the code, it is a pointer value in disguise (e.g. the compiler will substitute `"Hi!"` with an address to somewhere in memory containing the four bytes 'H', 'i', '!' and '\0'). For your variable `s`, the memory is already allocated when declared and an integral part of the variable, so assigning a pointer to an element does not make sense (type mismatch).

If you instead declare `s` as

```
char *s[10];
```

Then you are able to write your code as

```
s[1] = "Hi!";
printf("%s",s[1]);
```